No wifi option in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I have tried.
lshw -class network

*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0200000-c02fffff memory:c0800000-c0807fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
       logical name: enp3s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: d4:93:90:35:74:52
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:33 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0704000-c0704fff memory:c0700000-c0703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: c
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: enx9eddb42f6865
       serial: 9e:dd:b4:2f:68:65
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.179.43 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.


edited the lshw

Connect to the internet using USB tethering from your phone. Then, open the additional drivers tab in the software and sources application. Is any wifi driver listed? If so, install it and reboot.

No, it says no additional drivers available

Does this answer your question? My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?

I am also facing the same issue. How did you fix it?
